# Can a eventhandler delegate remove itself

Tags: c#, event-handling

How Can a eventhandler delegate remove itself ??

Code like this

```
    void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsHolding){
            return;
        }

        UtilityStoryboardManager.PlayerStoryboard("End", (_) =>{
            IsHolding = false;
            //call some function or  perform some logic
            timer.Stop();
            //How Can a eventhandler delegate remove itself ??
            //timer.Tick -= timerTick;
        }, null);
  }
```

Comment: Did you try it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsHolding){
        return;
    }

    UtilityStoryboardManager.PlayerStoryboard("End", (_) =>{
        IsHolding = false;
        //call some function or  perform some logic
        timer.Stop();
        //How Can a eventhandler delegate remove itself ??
        //timer.Tick -= timerTick;
    }, null);
 (sender as Timer).Tick-=timerTick; // removes the event
}
```